# How to sum or multiply two kernels from Tensorflow probability that act on different spaces?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

My specific problem concerns the MaternFiveHalves kernel from the tensorflow probability package, which is defined as:

```
z = sqrt(5) * ||x - y|| / length_scale
k(x, y) = (1 + z + (z ** 2) / 3) * exp(-z)
```

My input vectors (or "index_points") are two dimensional (x_1, x_2) and so I would like to have one length scale per dimension. It seems the easiest way to do this is to make two MaternFiveHalves kernels (one for each input) and multiply them:

```
k(x,y) = k_1(x_1,y_1)*k_2(x_2,y_2)
```

This post ([How to create sum of different kernel objects in TensorFlow Probability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56199905/how-to-create-sum-of-different-kernel-objects-in-tensorflow-probability?newreg=8a526e413e7a425b9e530fac732c8182)) already explains that kernels can be added or multiplied, but only when they act on the same space.

Is there a way to add or multiply kernels that act on different spaces? Or a way to restrict a kernel to only using a part of the input parameters and ignore the others?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that it can currently be easily done. I think you could easily write your own kernel, and maybe it'd make sense to have something this upstream in the main package. Roughly...

```py
class Blockwise(tfp.math.psd_kernels.PositiveSemidefiniteKernel):
  def __init__(self, kernels, block_sizes):
    self.kernels = kernels
    self.block_sizes = block_sizes
  def _apply(x1, x2, example_ndims):
    x1_parts = tf.split(x1, self.block_sizes)
    x2_parts = tf.split(x2, self.block_sizes)
    result = 1.
    for x1p, x2p, k in zip(x1_parts, x2_parts, self.kernels):
      result = result * k.apply(x1p, x2p, example_ndims)
    return result
```